# Android time zone confusion

Tags: android, date, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm confused as to why, under Settings -> Date & Time -> Select time zone (uncheck Automatic), Android says Eastern Time is GMT-4:00, when [everywhere else](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/definition/index.htm), Eastern Time is GMT-5?  The reason I ask, is that I'm trying to convert datetime values to the user's current time zone.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it from daylight savings time? In November when we no longer "save daylight", we will be GMT-5:00.

Comment: Yes. From http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=179 "Current time zone offset: UTC/GMT -4 hours".